# MiniZinc : how to implement custom search heuristics? (in Gecode)

Tags: constraint-programming, minizinc, gecode

For full context, my goal is to implement an "agent" that attempts to learn the best heuristic from a given pool in an online fashion (meaning that the learning and the solving procedures are done simultaneously). Essentially, the search strategy will be based on restarts : the solver should be able to switch between search heuristics at every restart based on observations accumulated during the search. Here are some previous works on the subject :

https://www.ijcai.org/proceedings/2022/258

https://drops.dagstuhl.de/opus/volltexte/2022/16661/

I believe that this cannot be done directly in MiniZinc and must be implemented directly in a solver (Gecode for example). I know very little about FlatZinc, solvers, and how the two interface. In truth, I come from a mathematical background and don't have much experience with programming in general. I can see that both MiniZinc and Gecode reference manuals go into great details, but since I can't seem to grasp the basics, they actually left me more confused than before.

So far I have downloaded Gecode source code, but even if I managed to implement my custom heuristic (which is a big if), I'm not sure what the next steps would be. How would I be able to use it in MiniZinc ?
I would really appreciate some general indications (keeping in mind I don't have much programming experience)!

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://www.minizinc.org/doc-2.6.4/en/mzn_search.html?highlight=search#) chapter in the MiniZinc documentation? With respect to Gecode as backend solver, [this](https://github.com/MiniZinc/libminizinc/issues/162#issuecomment-297203344) comment was inspiring to me. It is possible to set Gecode flags from within the MiniZinc IDE solver configuration form.

Answer (score 2):

Search heuristics in MiniZinc are generally managed through [search annotation](https://www.minizinc.org/doc-2.6.4/en/mzn_search.html).

When a solver implements a custom search heuristic, it generally adds a solver specific annotation. Examples for Gecode can be found in the [`gecode.mzn`](https://github.com/Gecode/gecode/blob/master/gecode/flatzinc/mznlib/gecode.mzn#L37-L60) file. Then to, for example, use the "relax and reconstruct" (random LNS) search heuristic, you can include the Gecode declarations and use it as a normal search heuristic:

```
include "gecode.mzn";
array[1..4] of var int: x;
solve ::relax_and_reconstruct(x, 90) maximize sum(x);
```

Like you described search heuristic, `relax_and_reconstruct` depends on restarts. As such, it would require you to use the restart flags to instruct the solver how (and when) to restart: `--restart-base`, `--restart`, `--restart-scale`, `--restart-limit`.

Implementing a custom search heuristic in Gecode can be tricky, but the [MPG](https://www.gecode.org/doc-latest/MPG.pdf) should provide a comprehensive guide. When you've created your new search heuristic, then you can add it to the FlatZinc processing [here](https://github.com/Gecode/gecode/blob/master/gecode/flatzinc/flatzinc.cpp#L1037-L1594) to add it to the created instance. (And add it to the earlier mentioned `gecode.mzn` file to make it available in MiniZinc.